# WordPress query mysql database by ID

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I would like to return results from the database which have a specific ID, and the other results which are not equal to that id. But must display the specified ID value first.

The query:

```
"SELECT ID, post_title, post_author, post_date
FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
AND ID = $sticky[0] 
ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT $postlimit"
```

This only returns the one result.
I also tried:

```
"SELECT ID, post_title, post_author, post_date
FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY $sticky[0], post_date DESC LIMIT $postlimit"
```

But this query returns no results, anyone know where I went wrong.
Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this, it will give you th record with the matching id first and than other records sorted by `post_date` in descending order....

```
SELECT ID, post_title, post_author, post_date
FROM `{$wpdb->prefix}posts`
WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY (CASE ID
            WHEN $sticky[0] THEN 1
            ELSE 2
          END),post_date DESC
LIMIT $postlimit;
```

Comment: Perfect exactly what i was after @Jacky Utwani :)